# Elasticsearch facet size

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 1.4.

I am querying my index using pagination (using from and size in the search query in order to have 20 results per page), and I have a limit of search hits set to 100 (So I cannot have more than 5 pages)

I am trying to use term facets, however the count field is global, it is across all  the search hits which can be more than 100.

## Here is a basic example:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20, 
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    } , "facets" : {
    "tags" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "tag"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to set a limit in ES facets to look only on the first 100 hits ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's an option provided by ElasticSeach for limiting the facets to results returned by the queries & filters.
You can set the `global` param to `true` or `false` for every facet. If no value is specified `global` is set to `true`.
Since you are looking at only returning the top 100 results, you should probably apply a `limit` filter to your query ([limit filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-limit-filter.html))

Try modifying your query like this:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20, 
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "limit" : {"value" : 100}
            }
        }
    }, 
    "facets" : {
        "tags" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tag"
            }
            "global": false
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to apply any filters to your data, you could try using the `limit` filter inside the `aggs` ([limit filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-limit-filter.html)):

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "limit_results": {
      "filter": {
        "limit": {
          "value": 100
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tags": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tag",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `size` param inside the second `aggs` is the number of tag groups returned. the default is `10` ([documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-facets-terms-facet.html)).

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the limit filter, however it is limiting the number of documents per shard, so if I have more than 1 shard the same search query might return different results